# div can rotate, span can't rotate but it can animate the transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attached code for three objects in html. Please have a look at the SO code playground or here: http://jsfiddle.net/kr34643L/

The first one (id1) is a **div** and I can rotate it via css3.

The second one (id2) is a **span** and it is not possible to rotate it in the same way.

But it is possible to rotate a **span** (id3) while doing the transition. Only it doesn't stay in that position.

I have seen answers about setting display to **block** or **inline-block**, but I honestly don't understand why I have to change the display style. Especially when the transition works well but only doesn't keep the position at the end.

```js
var id1 = document.getElementById('id1');
var id2 = document.getElementById('id2');
var id3 = document.getElementById('id3');

var rotate1 = 0;
var rotate2 = 0;
var rotate3 = 0;

id1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rotate1 = rotate1 ? 0 : 45;
    id1.style.transform = "rotate("+rotate1+"deg)";
});

id2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rotate2 = rotate2 ? 0 : 45;
    id2.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotate2 + "deg)";
});

id3.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rotate3 = rotate3 ? 0 : 45;
    id3.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotate3 + "deg)";
    id3.style.transition = "transform 2s";
});
```

```css
#id1, #id2, #id3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerbox">
  <div id="id1" style="cursor:pointer">div can rotate</div>
  <span id="id2" style="cursor:pointer">span doesn't</span><br>
  <span id="id3" style="cursor:pointer">span can transform though</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

- The description above is only valid for **Chrome**
- on **FireFox** id2 and id3 don't rotate and the transition of id3 doesn't work
- on **IE11** all rotations and id3's transition works

Comment: I have your `id2` `span` spinning on click when I apply: `position: absolute` not working, however, for the second span. Also I'm not seeing any transition on FF on the last element

Comment: @s0rfi949. Thanks for the hint about FF. My problem as described occurs on Chromium. I will check IE11 as well. So it's even more complicated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the CSS transform styles are not applied for the inline elements, since they are not considered as a block elements.

For the official answer check from the [W3 standard](http://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element).

As per the W3 standard of transformable element:

> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to **table-row**, **table-row-group**, **table-header-group**, **table-footer-group**, **table-cell**, or **table-caption** [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].

So you can't apply the transformation styles to **`<span>`** element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think? Then Chrome shouldn't show the transition as well?

Comment: Yes, even in Chrome also we can't apply the transform for span elements. But here you have applied the transition, it works like a virtual effect only. After completed that animation it can't maintain the state, it just returned to the inline style. I assume this may be the browser dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's of course sufficient to flag as accepted - but I still don't understand the restriction behind: Why did they define it at W3C to have transformation only for these block-level elements. I still don't understand that.

Comment: I have updated the detailed answer, please refer my below answer.

Answer (score 5):

As per the DOM, the block examples are **structural elements** while the inline elements are **text-based** (non structural).

[To see this](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/pmpnu3ao/) visually, refer the below screenshot:

[image: block vs inline elements in DOM]

From this you can see the **block** and **inline-block** elements having a clear structure (like a square or rectangle). But the **inline** elements are not having a proper structure (which having the break off blocks).

And we can't properly (generically) apply the transformation for these unstructured blocks, so that the **`<span>`** elements didn't support the transformation.